# Overescaped HTML on careers login canceled page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The error message on the canceled login page on Careers has raw `<br>` tags:

[image: Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:<br><br>Canceled]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and will go out shortly.